# How to using Firebase forEach query with varying nested data?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
myFirebaseDatabase
+accounts

 Instagram|account555555
 ->extraInfo
  ->counts
   ->*followed_by*
   ->follows
   ->media

 Facebook|account999999
 ->pages
  +0
   ->*fan_count*
  +1
```

The above is how part of the accounts section of my database is structured. What I am trying to do is write a node.js script that aggregates the total following of all accounts connected to our database. Each platform has its data structured differently making it challenging for me. Each Facebook account has multiple pages and each has their own fan_count (following), whereas Instagram is 1:1.

```
function getUsers(){

admin.database().ref("accounts").once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(accountSnapshot){
    overallFollowers = 0
    var instagram = accountSnapshot.val().extraInfo.counts;
    var facebook = accountSnapshot.val().pages;
    console.log(instagram);
    console.log(facebook);
  });
 });
};

getUsers();
```

I tried putting this together just to see if it would print something close to what I'm after. For console.log(instagram) it will print: { followed_by: 39402, follows: 136, media: 21 } and undefined if it's not an instagram page. For Facebook, it will print a much more complex array with fan_count included. I get an error if I try to call accountSnapshot.val().extraInfo.counts.followed_by.

Please help by pointing me in the right direction. How can I simply isolate followed_by and fan_count without dealing with the extra data so that I can add all these values together? Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think `Object.keys()` is the best instead of using `forEach`

```
admin.database().ref("accounts").once('value', function (snapshot) {   
  const accountSnapshot = snapshot.val() || {};

  Object.keys(accountSnapshot).sort().map(key => {
      if (accountSnapshot[key].extraInfo.counts.followed_by) {
          console.log(key, accountSnapshot[key].extraInfo.counts.followed_by);
      }

      if (accountSnapshot[key].pages.fan_count) {
          console.log(key, accountSnapshot[key].pages.fan_count);
      }
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Going to dig deeper into this today. I ran your code and got this error:

(node:42255) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'followed_by' of undefined
(node:42255) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

It's the same error I get if, in my previous code, I tried calling accountSnapshot.val().extraInfo.counts.followed_by.

What do you think the issue is?

Comment: does your database using firebase push keys?, whats the result of snapshot.val(), sorry I really cant do much here without seeing actual database json